# Proof clamped nurbs curve is tangent to first and last legs of its control points

Tags: proof-writing, curves, spline

I want to prove that $\mathbf{C}$ a quadratic NURBS curve is tangent to the first and last legs of its control polygon.

Given three control points $\mathbf{P}_0$, $\mathbf{P}_1$, $\mathbf{P}_2$ with positive real weights $w_0$, $w_1$, $w_2$

and

$$\mathbf{C}(t) =  \dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^{2} N_{i,2}(t) \cdot w_i \cdot \mathbf{P}_i}{\sum_{i=0}^{2} N_{i,2}(t) \cdot w_i}$$

With the knot vector

$$
U = (0,0,0,1,1,1)
$$

I know it's clamped and that's Nurbs are basically sharing b-splines properties so if we have clamped b-spline it will be tangent to it's first and last legs but I don't know how to give a proper proof for this.

Comment: You are going to have to explain your symbols if you want any chance of someone understanding your post. Even then it is going to be slim. Very few mathematicians ever work with NURBS ("Non-Uniform Rational Bezier Splines" for the curious). They are mostly used by graphic designers and engineers, and mostly researched by computer scientists. Even I am only familiar with the name, having looked at them once many years ago.